# How to deploy tornado websocket multiprocess application with supervisord?

Tags: deployment, multiprocessing, tornado, supervisord

I have an application (small part, unnecessary is skipped) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.websocket
import db_util # pg utility import

class SampleWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print u"open Websocket"
        do_init_stuff()

    def on_message(self, data):
        print u"%s BASE DATA RECIEVED:"
        print data
        do_on_message_stuff()

    def on_close(self):
        print u"WebSocket closed"
        do_on_close_stuff()

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        # Allow connect from all domains
        return True

def make_app(_settings):
    routes = [
        (r"/chat/sample/", handlers.SampleWebSocket),
    ]
    app = tornado.web.Application(routes)
    app.db = db_util.ConnectionRegistry()
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    port = 5001
    app.db = db_util.ConnectionRegistry()
    print " *** DEBUG:False, Starting Chat at port: %s" % port
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.bind(port)
    server.start(0) # actual number of cores == 2, so 2 subprocesses will be born
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I am trying to deploy it with supervisord. Here is part of supervisord config:

```
[program:chat]
directory=/home/me/chat
command=/home/me/venv/bin/python2.6 /home/me/chat/main.py
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)01d
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/chat.out.log
numprocs=1
numprocs_start=5001
```

When I start it at first time with **$ supervisord -c supervisord.conf** it starts, responds, but seems like supervisord does not control tornado child processes, so if I restart service with **$ supervisorctl restart**, I still have tornado childs living, binded to 5001 port. And service is unable to restart correctly.

So, does exists some way to configure supervisord for tornado with multiprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you're using supervisord you should be using supervisord's process groups instead of tornado's multi-process mode. Increase `numprocs` in the supervisor config and give each process a different port by passing `--port=%(process_num)s` in the command line (with a suitable option defined in the app itself). You'll need a proxy like nginx or haproxy to balance among the processes (or you could use file-descriptor passing to share one port as seen in https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/1073945, but this is an advanced usage and I recommend using a proxy instead).

Comment: Seems like, you are fully right. In the book about tornado i have found my case, cite:
"Most anecdotal reports from deployment teams recommend running one Tornado process per core."
Also after some researches I have founded out the fact that theads in that case can not share variables. So, the problem was caused by my misunderstanding of tornado principals and thread programming.